# Asp.Net core Custom ModelBinder HowTo get model from default binder

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

I like to create a custom Model Binder.

```
public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(Wrapper<SomeType>))
    {
        return;
    }

    var model = // get the model as if I would be using the default ModelBindig i.e. Complex modelbinding
 
    // manipulate 'model'
    
    return ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
}
```

Any Suggestions on the get the model as If i would be using the dfault modelbinding ....

Comment: Have a look at this [Custom model binder sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-model-binder-sample).